# Connecting a database from domain to domain

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have two domains one is www.abc.com and second one is www.xyz.in.I have a database connection file connect.php in www.xyz.in.I want to access this connection file in another domain www.abc.com.When iam trying to include this file using include("connect.php") iam getting this following error

Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'xyz_username'@'119.18.60.68' (using password: YES) in /home/officeau/public_html/mail/connection.php on line 7
cannot connect

here is my connection file

Comment: Connecting to a remote database server is often slow and not a good idea. Can you explain more about your situation? Are these domains running on two different servers? If not, why can't you simply copy the database credentials over?

Comment: Another thing is that on the remote server mysql may be blocking external connections because the default is to only allow connections for localhost

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the hostname of your other domain.It's not the localhost

```
$dbhost = 'YourOtherDomainHostName';
$dbuser = 'USERNAME';
$dbpasswd = 'PASSWORD';
$db = "DATABASE";

$dbh = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd) or die("Unable to connect to SQL server");
$my_db = @mysql_select_db($db) or die("Unable to select database");
```

**NOTE**:*don't use mysql.Mysql has been deprecated.Please use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli)*

Answer (score 0):

Agree with samitha's answer. Just also look if the database user is allowed to access remotely.

Like:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.* TO 'USERNAME'@'HostnameFromWhereYouAreConnecting';
```

OR

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'HostnameFromWhereYouAreConnecting';
```

if possible give only the necessary privileges and access to specific database.

**Update**:

Also if you can ssh, try connecting to other server from command line

```
mysql -h HOSTNAME -u USERNAME -p
```